# Brezis' exercise 6.15.3: if $0 \in \rho(T)$ then $\sigma(T^{-1}) = \frac{1}{\sigma(T)}$

Tags: functional-analysis, solution-verification, banach-spaces, spectral-theory

I'm trying to solve an exercise in Brezis' *Functional Analysis*, i.e.,

> Let $(E, |\cdot|)$ be a real Banach space. Let $T \in \mathcal L(E)$, i.e., $T:E \to E$ is a bounded linear operator. Let $I:E \to E$ be the identity map. Let $\rho(T)$ be the resolvent set of $T$. Let $\sigma(T)$ be the spectrum of $T$, i.e., $\sigma(T) := \mathbb R \setminus \rho(T)$.
>
> 1. Let $\lambda \in \mathbb R$ such that $\|T\| < |\lambda|$. Prove that
>    $$
>    \|I + \lambda (T-\lambda I)^{-1}\| \le \frac{\|T\|}{|\lambda|- \|T\|}.
>    $$
> 2. Let $\lambda \in \rho(T)$. Check that $(T-\lambda I)^{-1} T = T (T-\lambda I)^{-1}$ and prove that
>    $$
>    d(\lambda, \sigma(T)) := \inf_{h \in \sigma(T)} |\lambda-h| \ge \frac{1}{\| (T-\lambda I)^{-1} \|}.
>    $$
> 3. Assume that $0 \in \rho(T)$. Prove that $\sigma(T^{-1}) = \frac{1}{\sigma(T)}$.

There are possibly subtle mistakes that I could not recognize in below attempt of (3). Could you please have a check on it? I'm also happy to see other approaches.

---

Let $\lambda \neq 0$. It suffices to prove that $\lambda \in \sigma(T) \iff \frac{1}{\lambda} \in \sigma(T^{-1})$. It suffices to prove that $T-\lambda I$ is not bijective IFF  $T^{-1} - \lambda^{-1} I$ is not bijective. It suffices to prove that $T-\lambda I$ is bijective IFF  $T^{-1} - \lambda^{-1} I$ is bijective.

We have $0 \in \rho(T)$, so $T$ is bijective. Let $u, v \in E$. We have
$$
\begin{align}
(T-\lambda I)u=v &\iff Tu = v+\lambda u \\
&\iff u = T^{-1} v+ \lambda T^{-1} u \\
&\iff (T^{-1} - \lambda^{-1} I)u = -\lambda^{-1} T^{-1} v,
\end{align}
$$
so $(T^{-1} - \lambda^{-1} I)u = -\lambda^{-1} T^{-1} (T-\lambda I)u$. Then $T^{-1} - \lambda^{-1} I = -\lambda^{-1} T^{-1} (T-\lambda I)$. The claim then follows.

Comment: I think it's a little simpler to say $\lambda \in \sigma(T) \iff \exists v \neq 0~(Tv=\lambda v)$.  Then just apply $T^{-1}$ to both sides of that equation.

Comment: @RobertShore the spectrum $\sigma(T)$ does not necessarily coincide with the set of eigenvalues of $T$.

Comment: But if $T- \lambda I$ is not bijective, doesn't that mean $(T- \lambda I)v=0$ for some $v \neq 0$?  Or is it possible that $T - \lambda I$ is injective but not surjective?

Comment: @RobertShore It's from Remark 5 at page 161 that *"If $\dim E<\infty$, a linear operator from $E$ into itself is injective (= one-to-one) if and only if it is surjective (= onto). However, in infinite-dimensional spaces a bounded operator may be injective without being surjective and conversely"*.